# Limiting a Grouping in SQL

Tags: sql, netezza

I have some code that will calculate a running average of sales over time, and then measure the last 4 sales to see if they fall below 20% of this baseline.  I have it working for one customer at a time, but I need it to work for all customers.

```
select cust_nbr, avg(b) avg_baseline, sales from (
  select cust_nbr, baseline as b, sales from (
    select tbl.*,
       avg(sales) over(partition by cust_nbr order by cust_nbr, weekly rows between 12 preceding and current row) as rolling_avg, (rolling_avg*0.2) as baseline
     from (
       select cust_nbr, sum(sales) as sales, next_day(prcs_dt,'Sunday') - 1 as weekly from table
       where cust_nbr in ('1234')--, '2345', '3456')
       group by cust_nbr, weekly
     ) tbl
   ) tbl2
  order by weekly desc limit 4  --Limiting to 4 rows, need it to be 4 per group
) tbl3 group by cust_nbr, sales
```

Current output:

```
cust_nbr, avg_baseline, sales
1234, 20, 150
1234, 21, 160
1234, 23, 180
1234, 25, 140
```

Ideal output:

```
cust_nbr, flag
1234, 0
```

where flag would be whether or not the customer's sales had dropped below 20% of the rolling average for the last 4 sales

Answer (score 0):

You limit `group by` with the `having` clause. It's like the `where` clause, but it's used in conjunction with `group by`.